# Pandas resample

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have some irregularly stamped time series data of the following form,

```
         Time                 Pressure    Humidity    Temperature
2014-02-13 09:15:00.355000  124.283173   26.926562    6119.075
2014-02-13 09:15:00.356000  118.537935   22.228906    6111.625
2014-02-13 09:15:00.357000  118.537935   22.228906    6111.625
2014-02-13 09:15:00.359000  105.237890   10.919141    6104.625
2014-02-13 09:15:00.360000  105.237890   9.773438     6104.625...

2014-02-13 09:15:00.4530000  101.237890   7.773438     6101.625
2014-02-13 09:15:00.4590000  101.237890   7.773438     6101.625
```

I am trying to resample the data in pandas, to a regular 100 milliS or a S frequency. I expected this to work

x = ts.resample('100L', how='ffill')

That did not do anything, in fact it just gave me the same series back. Then I tried

x = ts.asfreq('100L', method = 'ffill') which seems to work. Am I doing something wrong? Is resample not meant to be used here?

Here I am looking to downsample to a 100 millisecond resolution, so my target output is

```
2014-02-13 09:15:00.355000   124.283173   26.926562    6119.075
2014-02-13 09:15:00.455000   101.237890   7.773438     6101.625
```

Answer (score 1):

You weren't explicit about what you want to output here -- based on the output from

`ts.asfreq('S', method = 'ffill')`

it seems you want to just take the first observation. Is that right?

But that is not what the ffill method does. When you pass how = 'ffill' to the resample method, it uses [dataframe.ffill](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html?highlight=ffill#pandas.DataFrame.ffill) which fills in null values. It's a synonym for

```
NDFrame.fillna(method=’ffill’)
```

If you want to use resample and return the first observation within each group, use the 'first' method:

```
ts_df.resample('S',how = 'first')
```

Comment: I apologize and you are right, so all I really doing is trying to downsample. In other words I have higher frequency data stamped at every millisecond and I am just trying to sample with a second resolution. And whenever there is a gap I want to resolve to the closest snapshot in the original data. Does that make sense?

Comment: So, are you really looking for a sampled series or do you just want to drop superfluous rows? You could maybe use `drop_duplicates` or a `groupby`.

Comment: @dqr Downsampling is a form of resampling so this should be the function for you! Resample also takes an argument `fill_method`, which can be set to `ffill` which I think is what you were trying to get to before. You should take a look at the [resample documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) which will give you more flexibility to customize.

Comment: Thanks exp 1orer, I will look into it. One last question, how is ts_df.resample('S',how = 'first') different from ts.asfreq('S', method = 'ffill'). Are they equivalent? And I really want the last observation before the timestamp changes, so for instance I am looking at a 'second' sampling I want to take the observation just before the timestamp changes and moves higher than my second resolution fire event.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
x = ts.resample('100L', method='ffill')
```

instead of

```
x = ts.resample('100L', how='ffill')
```