# Pandas: resampling irregular DateTime index / PeriodIndex

Tags: pandas, resampling

Trying to use Panda's .resample() function to upsample from irregular observations (e.g. from ca. 7 sec apart to hourly samples, use last observation). I keep getting this error message:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Grouper' has no attribute '_attributes'
```

even when using syntax from previously asked questions ([Pandas resample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274779/pandas-resample) and others). Pandas generally can use irregular Datetime index (from Cookbook)

My problem appears to be the *data format of the DataFrame* I'm trying to apply .resample() to, but I can't figure out what's wrong with it. Pandas version is 0.21.0 (from conda, on 64 bit linux,Python 3.6.4).

On some example data I see:

df.head()

```
                    x
date    
2017-12-18 07:01:15 20054.42
2017-12-18 07:01:24 20057.17
2017-12-18 07:01:32 20047.99
2017-12-18 07:01:40 20046.15
2017-12-18 07:01:49 20045.23
```

df.dtypes

```
x    float64
dtype: object
```

df.index

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-12-18 07:01:15', '2017-12-18 07:01:24', '2017-12-18 
07:01:32', '2017-12-18 07:01:40', '2017-12-18 07:01:49', '2017-12-18 
07:01:58', '2017-12-18 07:02:06', '2017-12-18 07:02:14', '2017-12-18 
07:02:22', '2017-12-18 07:02:31',
           ...
           '2017-12-29 03:00:11', '2017-12-29 03:00:19', '2017-12-29 
03:00:42', '2017-12-29 03:00:50', '2017-12-29 03:00:57', '2017-12-29 
03:01:04', '2017-12-29 03:01:11', '2017-12-29 03:01:20', '2017-12-29 
03:01:27', '2017-12-29 03:01:34'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', 
length=99492, freq=None)
```

Is df.resample('D') expected to work on this df, or does it need preprocessing? (Like setting something different from freq=None). I've seen work-arounds and manual code doing the same thing, but I would like to understand what is wrong with my data format. Using Pandas resample directly is cleaner long term as well.

The full stack trace error I'm getting is (but I can't see which bit I'm doing wrong from it, it is in the branch for a PeriodIndex):

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-5e18e9f3f0c1> in <module>()
     15 
     16 
---> 17 df['x'].resample('60S')

~/CODE/Python/anaconda2/envs/neo/lib/python3.6/site-      
packages/pandas/core/generic.py in resample(self, rule, how, axis, 
fill_method, closed, label, convention, kind, loffset, limit, base, on, 
level)
   5514         2000-01-01 00:03:00  0  4   8  12
   5515         """
-> 5516         from pandas.core.resample import (resample,
   5517                                           _maybe_process_deprecations)
   5518         axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)

~/CODE/Python/anaconda2/envs/neo/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pandas/core/resample.py in <module>()
   1008 
   1009 
-> 1010 class TimeGrouper(Grouper):
   1011     """
   1012     Custom groupby class for time-interval grouping

~/CODE/Python/anaconda2/envs/neo/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pandas/core/resample.py in TimeGrouper()
   1020         If axis is PeriodIndex
   1021     """
-> 1022     _attributes = Grouper._attributes + ('closed', 'label', 'how',
   1023                                          'loffset', 'kind', 
'convention',
   1024                                          'base')

AttributeError: type object 'Grouper' has no attribute '_attributes'
```

Comment: `df.resample('D').last()` works for me. This could be a bug, so please update to the latest - v0.21.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me! Could you maybe paste how you create a minimal, working DataFrame from static data? I've tried cobbling together something with two columns, 1xindex as ns64, and 1x random floats, with 5 rows, but still can't get it to work. I'm likely doing the same mistake in every example again. (Am already on v0.21.1). Some example I can get the dtypes from, and then clone.